# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder Error

Tags: logging, slf4j

Help, has anyone seen this error before?  Whenever I try to startup my WAS RAD 7 local server (Websphere Application Server v7.0 at localhost) on my PC I get the error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

I've included the following Jars in my class path:
log4j-1.2.15.jar
sl4j-api-1.7.5.jar
sl4j-log4j12.1.7.5.jar

Not sure what else needs to be included.  Thanks in advance for your help.

The Entire Message is below:
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R Reported exception:
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.hcsc.premier.provider.crosswalk.mdb.AbstractMessageDrivenBean.(AbstractMessageDrivenBean.java:32)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:167)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1328)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.loadBeanMetaData(EJSContainer.java:1998)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.loadBeanMetaData(HomeOfHomes.java:1140)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeRecord.getHomeAndInitialize(HomeRecord.java:444)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.getHomeWrapperCommon(EJSContainer.java:1549)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.getHomeInstance(EJSContainer.java:1289)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.startBean(EJSContainer.java:1273)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startBean(EJBContainerImpl.java:3489)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startModule(EJBContainerImpl.java:2681)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3826)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1122)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:609)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:725)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4520)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4698)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1271)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2043)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:439)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:382)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:615)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1086)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:967)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:031 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1299)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1195)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1155)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1086)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:967)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:334)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1265)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1360)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:750)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:158)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:622)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:475)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:513)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1574)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2841)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2714)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:63)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:150)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:90)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:541)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
[1/23/14 7:42:28:047 CST] 00000013 SystemErr     R  ... 93 more

Answer (score 0):

I discovered with a little digging that I was missing SLF4J JARs from the "JARs Dependency" Manifest file in my project.  Once added the runtime error was resolved.